# CSS: How do I get my "send" button to line up (move up) and size up (scale) properly?

Tags: css, button, stylesheet, vertical-alignment

If you take a peek at the page I'm trying to create, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kLUMs/3/), you'll see the issue I'm having pretty quickly.  I can't figure out why my send button isn't lined up or sized properly.  I've tried changing the height and width of the button, and I've tried adding a bottom margin.  The next thing I'm going to try is to change the line height, for the size.  I'm more worried about not getting everything aligned, though.  As long as everything lines up, it looks nice to me.  Can someone help me figure out why it isn't aligned?  Also, please ask if you need any additional details.

I've also tried `display:inline;` and various `float` settings.

Comment: oh.!! For the first time i have seen some one using a <div> to create a button.

Comment: @gout I hope you enjoyed that.  lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to float both the .button_outside_border and the .status_text to the left like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/SUXpN/). You still have a bit of cleaning up do to get it pixel perfect but this should get you underway.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I'm trying to get it to align vertically, though.  For example: `--` not `:`.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08, it *is* nicely vertically aligned. Float left without a clear and enough vertical space will line them up vertically.

Comment: It's just strange that even though you say that, and I can see it on JSFiddle in the result, the code doesn't reflect it.  I have 4 clears in my CSS, and the JSFiddle has 4 clears.  I changed it to float left.  All it does is position "Submit" directly underneath the text field.  I don't see any other change.

Comment: All I added was `float:left; margin-left: 10px;` to `.button_outside_border` and `float:left;` to `.text_message`. That did the trick right?

Comment: I retried that, and what it produces on my PC, in Chrome, is the message box on one line, and the 'Send' button on a new line, `10px` offset from the left side of the message box.

Comment: Okay, so I've realized what's been happening.  You are correct.  That does work.  I went through the code, line-by-line, and I found that `.message_text` was set to a width of 495px (too large).  Before changing that, I hadn't appended `float:left` to the `.text_message` div.

Comment: @joostchouten: Anyway, one thing that I'm really curious about is: why is it when I add `margin-bottom:200px` to the `.button_outside_border` div, it doesn't move at all?  XD  A big part of the reason I asked was to settle my curiosity about this strange behavior.

Comment: margin-bottom will never move the element itself. It will only ensure that the next element underneath it will be cleared 200px.

Comment: Thank you.  That's very useful info for me.  Also, your original answer was very insightful.  I have everything work now, of course.  Also, I took something away for my next endeavor.  Great answer.